# Add required attribute on all textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which have 4 columns..If the first column textbox have value I want to add "required" attribute on that row. I can do it manually by putting ID and add "required" but I have 70 rows. How to achieve this?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ab0ft11vn/ ........this image is my table if i input value on column "Financial Institution"  all the textbox on that row will be required. And if the second row column "Financial Institution" have no value then its row will not be required

Answer (score 0):

You can target the first column of the table using first-child selector like

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
    var $inputs = $('input', this),
        $input = $inputs.eq(0);
    if ($input.val()) {
        $input = $inputs.eq(1)
    }
    $input.attr('required', '');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sL3oh0jq/)

Comment: but if the second row, first column textbox have value i want to add required on the second row now.

Comment: if the first column have value, the second column on that row will be "required" not on the second row. but youre close

Comment: no not all inputs are required. it depends if the first row first column have value only that the second row will be requried

Answer (score 0):

dynamically change the required attribute:

```
$('#myTable td:first-child :text').change(function(){
    var elements = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:first-child) input');
    if($(this).val()){
        elements.attr('required', 'required');
    }else{
        elements.removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```